# Google Cardboard How to Change Distance Between Eyes

Tags: google-cardboard

My first message in Stack Overflow so apologies if I am not 100% aligned to the rules. Have searched here & google without any luck.

How do I change the Google Cardboard Unity prefab distance between the eyes. I am having an eye straining experiencing that the cameras appear to be either too close or too cock eyed (facing inwards) but any adjustment to the gameObjects gets re-set when played and I cant locate the right line of code from the scripts.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Apply a transform.Translate(x,y,z) script to each camera. It will move them to the world coords on play.

Answer (score 0):

Apply a transform.Translate(x,y,z) script to each camera. It will move them to the world coords on play.

You could also create an empty Game Object for each eye under the Main Camera and then make the eyes children of those objects. Then move the Game objects where ever you wish.